# Menu choice error, couldnt find any solution. menu identifier not found

Tags: c++

I have a question,
Im new to c++ and general with coding.
I have this problem Im coding right now an Loader for a game and want to make a choice menu.
I have this error and I dont know how to fix it.
If you could help I would be happy.

This is my code https://ghostbin.co/paste/x8hz3

```
int DLL();
int Beta();

int select()
{
    int selection;
    do
    {
        selection = menu();
        switch (selection)
        {
        case 1:    DLL();
            break;
        case 2:    Beta();
            break;  cout << "Exiting program.\n\n\n";  
        }
    } while (selection != 2);
    return 0;
}

int menu()
{
    int choice;
    cout << "Loader menu\n";
    cout << "--------------------------------\n";
    cout << "Normal\n";
    cout << "--------------------------------\n";
    cout << "1) Beta\n";
    cout << "--------------------------------\n";
    cout << "2) Dll methods\n";


    cin >> choice;
    while (choice < 1 || choice > 2)  // Check to see if user's input is correct
    {
        cout << "Invalid Selection. Enter 1, or 2: ";
        cin >> choice;
    }
    return choice;
}

int DLL()
{

    cout << "Test" << endl;

}

int Beta()
{

    cout << "Test" << endl;

}
```

Comment: What is your error? And when are you using `select` in your code?

Comment: why you cannot put the code here? Just copy it, select it all and press the `{}` button to get it formatted.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: you are trying to call `menu` before it is declared. You declared `DLL` and `Beta` before using it, do the same for `menu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to return anything for `select()` seemingly. You should declare the `main()` and write there:

```
.
select();
.
```

**Important:** You haven't defined any proper definition for `menu()`. On the beginning of the code, just add a single line `int menu();` and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you for the help!